# controller action is processing as html and not executing .js.erb file

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am trying to add datepicker to my application to pass date values to my controller and get the filtered records based on date range...but I keep getting errors...

Below is my expenses_controller action:

```
def dateFilter 
   @expenses = current_user.expenses.where(:created_at =>   params[:start_date]..params[:end_date])

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json { render json: @expenses }
    format.js
   end
end
```

My app/views/expenses/dateFilter.js.erb

```
$('.dateFilter').append('<%= escape_javascript(render(@expenses)) %>');
```

app/assets/javascripts/application.js

```
//= require turbolinks
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree .
//= require jquery.ui.all
//= require jquery.ui.datepicker

$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#date_form').submit(function (){  

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: "/expenses/dateFilter", 
      beforeSend: function (xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "text/javascript");},
     data: { 'start_date' : $("input[name='expense[start_date]']").datepicker(),  'end_date' : $("input[name='expense[end_date]']").datepicker()}
     success: function(data) { <%= render "expenses/dateFilter" %>}
});
```

});

and my dateFilter.html.erb partial is as below

```
<%= form_tag({:controller => 'expenses', :action => 'dateFilter'}, :class =>  'date_form', :remote => true) do %>
<%= datepicker_input "expense", :start_date, :class => 'dateFilter', :dateFormat => 'mm/dd/y' %>
<%= datepicker_input "expense", :end_date, :class => 'dateFilter', :dateFormat => 'mm/dd/y' %>
<%= submit_tag "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

my server logs are as below

```
Started GET "/expenses/dateFilter" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-01-02 15:49:39 +0530
ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Processing by ExpensesController#dateFilter as HTML
User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
Expense Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "expenses".* FROM "expenses" WHERE "expenses"."user_id" = ? AND ("expenses"."created_at" BETWEEN NULL AND NULL) ORDER BY created_at DESC  [["user_id", 1]]
Rendered expenses/dateFilter.html.erb within layouts/application (90.0ms)
```

Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 304ms

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `datepicker_input' for #<#<Class:0x000000037b87e0>:0x00000003500570>):
1: <%= form_tag({:controller => 'expenses', :action => 'dateFilter'}, :remote => true) do %>
2:     <%= datepicker_input "expense", :start_date, :class => 'dateFilter', :dateFormat => 'mm/dd/y' %>
3:     <%= datepicker_input "expense", :end_date, :class => 'dateFilter', :dateFormat => 'mm/dd/y' %>
4:     <%= submit_tag "Submit" %>
5:     <% end %> 
app/views/expenses/dateFilter.html.erb:2:in `block in _app_views_expenses_date_ilter_html_erb__2248059185612722443_31189320'
app/views/expenses/dateFilter.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_expenses_date_ilter_html_erb__2248059185612722443_31189320'
app/controllers/expenses_controller.rb:42:in `dateFilter'
```

someone please help me slove my issues...

Answer (score 0):

The range queries work only on DateTime objects and you're passing Strings inside. Try converting the params to datetime object and it should work

@expenses = current_user.expenses.where(:created_at =>   (params[:start_date].to_datetime)..(params[:end_date].to_datetime))

Comment: Thanks for the answer but my dateFilter.js.erb is not getting executed. Controller action is executed as html instead of js. It gives me missing template error.

Comment: Based on the error you've shown in your question, the @expenses object is nil and that's why the render object is throwing an error.  But the one you're talking about now seems different than the one in the question? Do you have a datefilter.html.erb for rendering your html? Please post the entire error stack so that I can help you better.

Comment: Yes adding to_datetime gave me noMethoderror but it helped my find a typo which after fixing I am now getting Missing template error.

Comment: I have _dateFilter.html.erb partial which I have shown here above logs. I have also edited logs to show Missing template error.

Comment: Hey, _dateFilter is a partial. Please rename your file to dateFilter.html.erb, and It should work. Please remember that Rails philosophy is convention over configuration. You need to follow that specifically.

Comment: I have edited my logs after renaming my _dateFilter.html.erb to dateFilter.html.erb

Comment: Sunny, You are having a chain of issues. While the original issue is resolved, you keep encountering more errors. You're using a custom method     datepicker_input, but that's not defined anywhere and that's causing the issue. I'd suggest you to debug and try to identify the issue by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Your `form_tag` has a `:class =>  'date_form'` and `:remote => true` and should get submitted correctly as a javascript request. BUT the code in `application.js` you have

`$('#date_form').submit(`

which means that `date_form` is not a class, but an id.

Is there another form with with `date_form` as an id?

I would suggest putting `console.log("is this even getting executed");` in your `application.js` right before

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
```

Comment: As u suggested I added console.log and it does not seem to be exucuted even if i remove :class => 'date_form' from my form_tag and $('#date_form').submit(.. from my application.js. I have edited my logs after renaming my _dateFilter.html.erb to dateFilter.html.erb.